# Removing common words from a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to filter common words to end up with a city name.

Here's what I have:

```
import re
ask = "What's the weather like in Lexington, SC?"
REMOVE_LIST = ["like", "in", "how's", "hows", "weather", "the", "whats", "what's", "?"]
remove = '|'.join(REMOVE_LIST)
regex = re.compile(r'\b('+remove+r')\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
out = regex.sub("", ask)
```

and it outputs:

```
nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x for x in ask.split() if x.lower() not in REMOVE_LIST]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should escape strings to match literally because some characters have special meaning in regular expression (For example `?` in the `REMOVE_LIST`):

Use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape such characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape('?')
'\\?'

>>> re.search('?', 'Lexington?')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
>>> re.search(r'\?', 'Lexington?')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002C68100>
>>>
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> ask = "What's the weather like in Lexington, SC?"
>>> REMOVE_LIST = ["like", "in", "how's", "hows", "weather", "the", "whats", "what's", "?"]
>>> remove = '|'.join(map(re.escape, REMOVE_LIST))
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + remove + r')\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> out = regex.sub("", ask)
>>> print out
     Lexington, SC?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to *find* the words:

```
import re

sentence = "What's the weather like in Lexington, SC?"
words = re.findall(r"[\w']+", sentence.lower())
remove = {"like", "in", "how's", "hows", "weather", "the", "whats", "what's", "?"}

print set(words) - remove
```

Sets are unordered, so if order is important, you can filter the list of words with a list comprehension:

```
[word for word in words if word not in remove]
```